# React ignore required on form input

Tags: html, reactjs

I try to validate the form input so that you can't submit the form without completing the description text input

```
<input placeholder="Description" type='text' name="description" className="form-control" value={this.state.description} onChange={this.changeDescriptionHandler} required />
```

But when i submit the form, it let's me submit it with the empty input, even though i specified "required". What could be the problem?

PS, State looks like this

```
this.state = {
            description: '',
            name: '',
            birthDate: '',
            gender: 'MALE'
        }
```

and the submit

```
saveCasefile = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        let patient = { name: this.state.name, birthDate: this.state.birthDate, gender: this.state.gender }
        let casefile = { description: this.state.description, patient: patient };
        CaseFilesService.createCasefile(casefile).then(res => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        })
    }
```

Comment: Try required={true}

Comment: Can you share the code showing how is the form submitted?

Comment: @chrisg86 , done

Comment: How are you calling `saveCaseFile()`?The `required` attribute only works for traditional `<input type="submit">` forms; React apps often just use inline click handlers instead of "real" forms, so won't be able to use this attribute (unless you do [extra work](https://thewebdev.info/2020/04/29/how-to-add-a-react-input-with-a-required-attribute/) to support it)

Comment: @DanielBeck , i think you are right, I'm calling it by: <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.saveCasefile}>Save</button>

Comment: Your form should look like `<form onSubmit={this.saveCasefile}>` and you should remove the `onClick` handler of that button.

Answer (score -2):

set the condition in submit handler function.

```
if(this.state.description !== ''){ .... }
```